# connect function in pyqt5 does not work

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyside

I recently moved from `pyside` to `pyqt5` and there is a problem. I looked it up online and apparently, it already happened to people who used `pyqt4` and moved to `pyqt5`. However, it didn't really help... I tried to add `pyqtSignal` after `Qobject` but it is still not working. Please help.
these are my code lines:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"),Dialog.accept)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("rejected()"), Dialog.reject)
```

and this is what appears when I run it:

```
AttributeError: type object 'QObject' has no attribute 'connect'
```

Answer (score 2):

[from the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#connecting-disconnecting-and-emitting-signals):

```
connect(slot[, type=PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.AutoConnection[, no_receiver_check=False]])
```

> Connect a signal to a slot. An exception will be raised if the connection failed.
>   Parameters:
>
> - `slot` – the slot to connect to, either a Python callable or another bound signal.
> - `type` – the type of the connection to make.
> - `no_receiver_check` – suppress the check that the underlying C++ receiver instance still exists and deliver the signal anyway.

---

for your example:

```
self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept) # pyqt5
```

> <s>QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox.rejected, Dialog.reject) # pyqt4</s>

<sub>As a sidenote, "Dialog" sounds like a class, you probably want to connect to an instance, else think about naming your instances with lowercase front-letters ...</sub>

Comment: Hi, thank you. What you said that was not tested actually worked. However, what you did test is not working... it sais like before: AttributeError: type object 'QObject' has no attribute 'connect' (and i did add the accepted like you said so.

Comment: @AliciaBelhassen. You cannot use the `QObject.connect` way of connecting signals in pyqt5. You **must** use `self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)`. I suggest you read this: [Differences Between PyQt4 and PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html).